# Why do my two similar mysql queries have different execution times?

Tags: mysql, limit, execution-time

I am using mysql, and I have two queries:

```
SELECT *
FROM `default_orders`
JOIN `default_document` ON `documentid`= `document_id`
JOIN `default_users` ON `default_users`.`id`= `user_id`
WHERE `user_id` IN (SELECT `user_id`
FROM `default_user_info`
WHERE `institute_id` =  '2')
 LIMIT 1500, 500
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM `default_orders`
JOIN `default_document` ON `documentid`= `document_id`
JOIN `default_users` ON `default_users`.`id`= `user_id`
WHERE `user_id` IN (SELECT `user_id`
FROM `default_user_info`
WHERE `institute_id` =  '2')
 LIMIT 500
```

It takes 8.1509 seconds for the first query to execute, but the second takes only 2.0000 seconds.
In first query `LIMIT 1500, 500` convert to `LIMIT 500`.
How i can decrease the execution time for first query?

Comment: Without an ORDER BY both are more or less a random sample of 500 rows ...

Comment: With `LIMIT 500` MySQL has to find the first 500 rows and select them. With `LIMIT 1500, 500` MySQL has to find 1500 rows and skip them - Then find next 500 rows and select them. So the first query has to find 2000 rows - 4 times more than the first one, and thus it needs 4 times more time. You should try to increase the performance of both queries by defining the correct indexes. Post the table definitions (`SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name`) and EXPLAIN result (`EXPLAIN SELECT * ...`) so we can see, what indexes you are missing.